# How do I hook into the blur event of the v-currency-field?

Tags: vue.js, input, vuetify.js, hook, onblur

I'm writing a vue.js application with the v-currency-field package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-currency-field

When I read the documentation, I see nothing for a blur event (or any events at all): https://phiny1.github.io/v-currency-field/started.html#introduction

I'm getting around this by selecting the input inside the v-currency-field like this:

```
const holdbackAmountInput = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Holdback amount"]')[0];
holdbackAmountInput.addEventListener('blur', this.holdbackAmountInputBlurHandler);
```

But is there not a better way to do this? It gets more complicated than the above code because I have to run it in the updated() hook and check if the holdbackAmountInput exists, and if it does, I have to assign it to a data object so that I have a reference to it when I have to remove the event listener when it's removed from the DOM or when the component is destroyed. Seems needlessly complicated for something that should be really simple.

Is there not a simpler way to do  this?

Comment: why do you need blur event? you can use `v-model`

Comment: v-model catches changes in the value, not blur events.